# operator= ambiguity in junction with conversion operators

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading, ambiguity

I have the following situation:

```
    class B;

    class A {
    private:
        int n;
    public:
        A& operator=(const A& a) {
        }

        A& operator=(const int n) {
            this->n = n;
        }

        friend class B;
    };

    class B {
    private:
        A a;
    public:
        operator A&() {
            return a;
        }

        operator int&() {
            return a.n;
        }
    };
```

When I execute this code:

```
    A a;
    B b;
    int i = b;
    a = b;
    a = i;
```

I have the following error:

```
    error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
    ..\CrossPPTest\TestProxy.cpp(40): could be 'A &A::operator =(const int)'
    ..\CrossPPTest\TestProxy.cpp(37): or       'A &A::operator =(const A &)'
    while trying to match the argument list '(A, B)'
```

How to resolve this ambiguity assuming I can not add

```
A& operator =(const B&)
```

to class A.

There are complex reasons why I have to do exactly like this, but it would be really nice if thing like this will work.

May be there are some priorities or something like explicit keyword for operators... Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

UPDATE:
Any kind of casts can not be used in second part of code. The thing is to find a solution modifying the first code part only.

ONE MORE UPDATE:
Code part #2 MUST compile as is.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I know about explicit casts, but thanks. The reason why I can't use it is that the second part of code will be written by other developers and I want to make it as easy as possible.

Comment: If you know about explicit casts and don't want to use them then why don't you put that in your question.

Comment: @SethCarnegie There are no base classes...

Comment: "Explicit cast" is redundant. Should this be "explicit conversion"? or perhaps "Use a cast"?

Comment: @PeteBecker Neither is really a solution, because it should be used by other developers as is.

Comment: What you have here is bad design.

Comment: @Daniel - my point is about **terminology**. **All** casts are explicit; you write them in source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. Some conversions can be done without a cast; they are "implicit conversions". Some require a cast; they are "explicit conversions".

Comment: @PeteBecker Anyway implicit conversions only accepted.

Comment: As @SethCarnegie said, this is a design problem, not a coding problem.

Comment: @PeteBecker OK, let's change the task. The code part #2 must compile without modifications and I can not add operator=(B&) to class A.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for polymorphism:

```
class B;

class A {
   int n;
   public:
      A& operator=(const A& a) {...}

    A& operator=(const int n) {
      this->n = n;
      return *this;
    }

    friend class B;
};

class B : public A {
   A a;
   public:
     operator int&() {
         return a.n;
     }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    int i = b; // works
    a = b; // works
    a = i;
}
```

***[Demo](http://liveworkspace.org/code/zlu41%248)***

Comment: Read the comments to the question. Inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The way you posed makes the problem substantially unsolvable.

There are clearly two ways to assign to an `A` from a `B`, none of which is preferable.

The only solution (without touching the classes) is to explicitly cast, so that you force which conversion has to take place.

In general, assignment and conversion are redundant: if you admit implicit conversion (either to - with `U::operator T() const` - or from - with `T::T(const U&)` ) you don't have to provide assignment other than the default, and if you want implicit heterogeneous assignments, you must not provide conversion, or at most make them `explicit`.